# Which exploding Tardis exploded in what explosion?

Tags: doctor-who, tardis

In the Doctor Who episode *Journey to the Centre of the TARDIS* the Tardis is exploding. Is this connected to the exploding Tardis in the series 5 episodes *The Pandorica Opens* and *The Big Bang*?

I know it was the Silence that triggered the explosion to stop the return of the Time Lords and a return to the Time War.  What I don't know is if these were two separate explosions or one explosion connected by a temporal paradox?

Answer (score 3):

There is a connection between the [episodes](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Journey_to_the_Centre_of_the_TARDIS_%28TV_story%29) beyond The TARDIS exploding:

> The Doctor steps through a time rift in order to undo the TARDIS' crash, much like how he previously walked into a crack in time and space in order to prevent the TARDIS from exploding and erasing all of reality.

I can find no further connection, however. These are not the only episodes in which The TARDIS is [essentially destroyed](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Frontios_%28TV_story%29). Each of these incidences appear to have separate causes and, as of yet, no deeper connections.

Comment: I know you're just quoting the wikia, here, but IMO that's a pretty bizarre interpretation of the ending of The Big Bang. To me, The Doctor stepping into the crack was inevitable, because he had *already* undone the event that created them.

Answer (score 2):

As far as we know, there's no direct connection between the two events.

In "The Big Bang", *something* has forced the TARDIS to a specific point in time -- something directly relevant to Amy's wedding -- and caused it to explode. We know the Silence are supposedly to blame for this, but as of yet we have no idea *how* they pulled it off. This explosion "really happened", but The Doctor was able to reverse it's effects by using the Pandorica itself. In particular, the cracks in the universe existed *before* the explosion (rippling back in time), but closed naturally afterwards.

On the other hand, in "Journey to the Centre of the TARDIS", we know why the TARDIS is in danger of exploding: the salvage crew has somehow damaged it and compromised the security of it's fuel containment system. There's no indication that the Silence had anything to do with it. It has no apparent connection to Amy Pond, and there was no mention of cracks in the wall. In addition, The Doctor was able to undo this explosion "locally" -- causing a paradox that reset time a few days, as opposed to having to reboot the entire universe.

The possibility of the TARDIS exploding is a pretty generic "danger". There doesn't seem to be any reason to expect all such incidents to be connected to each other.